# error in importing Http/http.dart package

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-packages

I updated the dependencies with proper indentation, then flutter pub get and then import it in the code. Tried to restart my ide as well. The error pops up when i try to build the application.

Error:

> Unable to find modules for some sources, this is usually the result of
>   either a bad import, a missing dependency in a package (or possibly a
>   dev_dependency needs to move to a real dependency), or a build failure
>   (if importing a generated file).
>
> Please check the following imports:
>
> `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;` from myapp|lib/myapp.dart
>   at 83:1

Code:

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'dart:async';

     void main(){
       runApp(MaterialApp(
         home: HomePage(),
       ));
     }

     class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {

       @override
       _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
     }

     class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {


       Future getData() async{
         http.Response response = await http.get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees");
         debugPrint(response.body);
       }

       @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        getData();
      }

       @override
       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
         return Scaffold(
           appBar: AppBar(
             title: Text("Employees"),
             backgroundColor: Colors.green,
           ),
         );
       }
     }
```

pubspec.yaml

```
    name: myapp
    description: A new Flutter project.

    # The following defines the version and build number for your application.
    # A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
    # followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
    # Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
    # build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
    # In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
    # Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
    # In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
    # Read more about iOS versioning at
    # https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
    version: 1.0.0+1

    environment:
      sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

    dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter

      http: ^0.12.0+4

      # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
      # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter


    # For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
    # following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

    # The following section is specific to Flutter.
    flutter:

      # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
      # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
      # the material Icons class.
      uses-material-design: true

      # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
      # assets:
      #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
      #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

      # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

      # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
      # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

      # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
      # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
      # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
      # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
      # example:
      fonts:
        - family: IndieFlower
          fonts:
            - asset: fonts/IndieFlower-Regular.ttf

      #
      # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
      # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

[image]

Comment: pubspec.yaml file    dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  
  http: ^0.12.0+4

Comment: clean flutter and try again

Comment: @NavinKumar still the same error.

Comment: The easiest way I was able to solve it was to change from beta channel to master channel. I would suggest anyone facing this issue to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried restarting your IDE?

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages

> Stop and restart the app, if necessary If the package brings
>   platform-specific code (Java/Kotlin for Android, Swift/Objective-C for
>   iOS), that code must be built into your app. Hot reload and hot
>   restart only update the Dart code, so a full restart of the app might
>   be required to avoid errors like MissingPluginException when using the
>   package.

Comment: can you update the question with your indented pubspec file?

Comment: hi i just updated the entire pubspec file under the code. Please have a look

Comment: Recently when I had a similar issue, I tried the following.  Step 1) Create a brand new blank flutter project.  Step 2) Update the pub spec.yaml file.  Step 3) Run the flutter pub get, Step 4) Copy the dart pages and assets from the previous project over into the new one.  Step 5) Rebuild and test again.  That got it to work for me.

Comment: @ArthurEKing thank you. It has solved this problem. The application is getting built for the web now but when it is attempting to connect to the browser instance, i am getting an error saying "Failed to establish connection with the application instance in Chrome.
This can happen if the websocket connection used by the web tooling is unabled to correctly establish a connection, for example due to a firewall."

Comment: Well I'm glad it worked!  But yeah, I wish I knew why that happens...  I think it has something to do with some of the project settings when it's first created?  Not sure.  Either way, hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I see your `Flutter` version is 1.13.6. 
I also experienced some strange problems with this version, but when I switched to `dev` channel all the problems are gone.

Try this too:

```
 flutter channel dev
 flutter upgrade
```

Comment: the problem still persists after trying this.

Answer (score 0):

do not use vscode run&debug feature , use this command to run flutter run -d web-server --web-hostname= --web-port= --profile -v ,replace "ipaddress" and "freeport" with your system input